# jQuery animate the line-height and font-size

Tags: jquery, css, height

I have a div panel wich has font-size of 20 and line-height of 100 px but I want to animate it to have font-size 15 and line-height 50 so the block keeps the font and reduces the height.. here is what I tried

```
$("#homepage_panel").animate({
    height: '50px',
    lineHeight: '50px',
    fontSize: '10px'
}, 500, function() {
    $("#login_form").slideDown("fast");
});
```

but the code only changes the height of the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you preset the starting *line-height* and *font-size* in CSS.

```
#homepage_panel {
    line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}​
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/rT4gs/1/)